# Compiling Objective-C for Windows on a Mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, windows-7, windows-xp, compilation

I am programming an application for OS X, and a friend of mine wants me to make it for Windows. Can this be done? I have two other questions that related to this one, to closely related for me to ask another question.

- 1: Can I use my Nib files to build the interface for Windows?
- 2: If you answered my original question, does your solution work for all kinds of Windows (Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows 7, ect)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a project called [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/) that aims to allow you to compile Objective-C for other platforms. It looks like their website says that (for Windows) it works on all NT-based Windowses. I think it allows you to reuse your Nibs, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

There is also GNUstep and Cygwin, it is kind of ugly, but I have used it in the past. Works on linux too.

Comment: Does it let me use my Nib files? Which platforms and operating systems can it compile for? More information would be very helpful.

Comment: memory a little fuzzy on them, Gorm (their IB) supports 10.2+ NIBS, and the xcode project can be converted to their IDE's project file.

Comment: Ok. It sounds great, but I have no idea how to use it, and all they say is.... well.... nothing at all.

Comment: yeah I had a hard time with it too, installation instructions are here: http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Installation_on_Windows , development applications are: http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Category:Development_Applications specifically Gorm and Project Manager

Comment: Ummm.... wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Installation_on_Windows... I have a Mac running OS X. I thought I made that very clear.

Comment: I thought your friend wanted you to port it to windows.

Comment: But I have to do this from a Mac. Is there a way to compile a Windows executable on a Mac?

Comment: If you want to port a cocoa application to run on windows, the easiest way that I have ever done is to port it to GNUStep, you can continue developing on the mac using X11 and GNUStep. http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Cross_Compiling#I_have_an_Xcode_project_and_want_to_run_on_Windows